# Cast SSIS string to Integration Services Data Type

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm working on a `Custom Data transformer`. When the inputs a user has give in in a text field I need to test to be sure that its the proper data type for that field.

Is it possible to cast / parse a string in C# to a SSIS Data Type?  [Integration Services Data Types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx)  the list of possible data types is rather daunting. If I have to make a huge case statement to test for each one its going to be a lot of code.

Does anyone have a better option?

Comment: I can't really do at try catch parse on every one of the datatypes that would just be ugly in the worst sense of ugly.

Comment: That's often the nature of parsing -- thorough code -- but you could simplify by using datatypes that are supersets of others.  So, you first check whether all you've got is digits (not even decimal points), in which case you store it as the biggest possible integer (DT_I8);  non-integers (whether float or currency) get stored as the biggest float (DT_R8);  then, valid date-times (even when only a date) get stored as date-times (DT_DATE);  and everything else -- what fails the above -- gets stored as unicode strings (DT_WSTR, or if pasting in large amounts of text is allowed, DT_NTEXT).